# Как реализовать универсальную функцию поиска и сортировки по таблице в Django с помощью api queryset?

Tags: python, django, сортировка, search

Делаю страницу с табличкой, которая содержит поля с информацией из базы данных. Хочу над каждым столбцом сделать формочку поиска по параметрам, но не могу придумать никакого универсального решения кроме как через if-else проверять наличие кучи параметров в request.GET. Я уверен, что решение моей проблемы уже известно и существует уже довольно давно, но я никак не могу сформулировать вопрос чтобы найти это в гугле.
В общем, сейчас проверка и фильтрация выглядит следующим, мягко говоря, не самым красивым способом:

```
#   поиск
    if 'name' in request.GET:
        list = list.filter(name__icontains=request.GET.get('name'))
        cache.name = request.GET.get('name')
        cache.save()
    elif cache.name is not '':
        list = list.filter(name__icontains=cache.name)

    if 'number' in request.GET:
        list = list.filter(number__icontains=request.GET.get('number'))
        cache.number = request.GET.get('number')
        cache.save()
    elif cache.number is not '':
        list = list.filter(number__icontains=cache.number)

# и далее, далее, далее...
```

При чем такая конструкция находится в каждом представлении, отвечающем за отображение таблицы, а таблиц много. Поэтому такое решение совершенно не подходит.
Я хочу сделать что-то вроде универсальной функции поиска, которая бы вызывалась в каждом view и возвращала бы отфильтрованный и отсортированный список объектов, которые потом будут отображаться в таблице.
Я это вижу примерно таким образом:

```
def search_and_sort(request, list, cache_instanse):
    for search_seting in request.GET:
        if cache_instanse.search_seting is not '':
            list = list.filter(search_seting__icontains=cache_instanse.search_seting)
        else:
            list = list.filter(search_seting__icontains=request.GET.get(search_seting))
            cache_instanse.search_seting = request.GET.get(search_seting)
            cache_instanse.save()
    return list
```

cache_instance - это объект кэша для каждой отдельной таблички, он хранит значения полей при предыдущих поисковых запросах, по факту копирует объект таблицы, только все его поля класса CharField.
Вариант с кодом выше не работает, так как я не могу передать в качестве строки имя переменной (это решало бы всю проблему) и просто проитерироваться по строкам, представленным в request.GET не представляется возможным.
Уважаемые мидлы, сеньеры и джуны-переростки, если кто-то может чем-то помочь, сказать куда я думаю не так или показать готовое решение, прошу, помогите пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

UPD:
Я справился с сортировкой. Не могу понять как сделать поиск.
Сортировка выглядит следующим образом:

```
def search_and_sort(request, list, instance, cache_instance):
    #   перебор всех параметров, переданных в request.GET
    for setting in request.GET:
        #   проверка на ключ сортировки
        if setting is 'sorted' or setting is 'resort':
            #   если нужно отсортировать от большего к меньшему
            if setting == 'sorted' and request.GET.get(setting) is not '':
                list = list.order_by('-'+request.GET.get(setting))
            #   если нужно отсортировать от меньшего к большему
            else:
                list = list.order_by(request.GET.get(setting))
    return list
```

Чтобы провернуть такое же решение с поиском типа Object.objects.filter(field__icontains=request.GET.get(setting)) нужно чтобы вместо fields подставлялось имя переменной. Как получить имя переменной я знаю, не знаю только как передать.

Я планировал сделать это следующим способом:

```
def search_and_sort(request, list, instance, cache_instance):
    #   перебор всех параметров, переданных в request.GET
    for setting in request.GET:
        #   проверка на ключ сортировки
        if setting is 'sorted' or setting is 'resort':
            #   если нужно отсортировать от большего к меньшему
            if setting == 'sorted' and request.GET.get(setting) is not '':
                list = list.order_by('-'+request.GET.get(setting))
            #   если нужно отсортировать от меньшего к большему
            else:
                list = list.order_by(request.GET.get(setting))
        #   если это ключ поиска
        else:
            fields = instance._meta.get_fields()
            for field in fields:
                if field.name == setting:
                    list = list.filter(field__icontains=request.GET.get(setting))
    return list
```

Кто знает как мне помочь или знает решение лучше, прошу не проходить мимо.

Comment: Я бы хотел сказать, что если Вы с сортировкой справились - то справитесь и с поиском. Тут главное - желание :-) Задача то не особо сложная, гораздо больше времени уйдет на понимание ограничений, котрые есть в используемом инструменте, чем на само решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Object.objects.filter(field__icontains=request.GET.get(setting)) нужно чтобы вместо fields подставлялось имя переменной

Делайте так:

```
filters = {
    '{}_icontains'.format(setting): request.GET.get(settings)
}
Object.objects.filter(**filters)
```

`**` разворачивает `dict` в список именованных параметров функции. Как раз то, что нужно, если имена параметров динамические.